# Is it possible to load django admin inlines dynamically?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i.e, load the inlines only when clicked on it. If possible, how can this be achieved. I have gone through various answers but could not find what I was looking for.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569091/django-admin-add-inlines-dynamically at all helpful? It's dealing with another way of loading inlines "dynamically", but do any of those solutions help?

Comment: @bouteillebleu No this does not help. I dont want to add new inlines dynamically, rather I want to load them dynamically. Hope you understood.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax has some advice on how to add sections to Django forms with Javascript - is that closer to what you're looking for?